# How to write where clause in mysqldump when there are more than one table?

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have `database1` in which I have `table11` and `table12`.

My `table11` is:

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 82 |
| 2 | 23 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 29 |

My `table12` is -

| id | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | pen |
| 2 | pencil |
| 3 | copy |
| 4 | laptop |

Here on `table11` and `table12` separately I can successfully execute `mysqldump` `--where` filtering option with an `AND` clause as I have demonstrated below -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table11 --where="col1<=50 AND col1>=25" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_col1_lessthanorequalto_50_where_col1_greaterthanorequalto_25.sql
Enter password:
```

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table12 --where="col1 LIKE 'p%' AND col1 LIKE '%n'" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table12_where_col1_like_p-percent_and_col1_like_percent-n.sql
Enter password:
```

Now I want to execute `mysqldump` `--where` filtering options on both the tables at the same time. I tried the following two methods but both throw error -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1  --where="table11.col1<=50 AND table12.col1 LIKE 'p%'" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_table11_col1_lessthanorequalto_50_and_table12_col1_like_p-percent.sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `table11` WHERE table11.col1<=50 AND table12.col1 LIKE 'p%'': Unknown column 'table12.col1' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table11 table12 --where="table11.col1<=50 AND table12.col1 LIKE 'p%'" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_table11_col1_lessthanorequalto_50_and_table12_col1_like_p-percent.sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `table11` WHERE table11.col1<=50 AND table12.col1 LIKE 'p%'': Unknown column 'table12.col1' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

I thought may be `--where` filtering option won't successfully take <table>.<column> format. So I tried the following with a single table and it executes successfully -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table11 --where="table11.col1>=25" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_col1_greaterthanorequalto_25.sql
Enter password:
```

So indeed the problem is filtering on two tables at the same time.

To see if a table can be selected in `--where` filtering options when only `database` name is provided I try -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --where="table11.col1>=50" > /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_table12_where_table11_col1_greaterthanorequalto_50.sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `table12` WHERE table11.col1>=50': Unknown column 'table11.col1' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

So, my earlier first attempt definitely showed error but my second attempt should definitely work? But there also error.

Now I try the following approach but still get error -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table11 --where="table11.col1>=50"  table12 --where "table12.col1 LIKE '%n'"> /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_table11_col1_greaterthanorequalto_50_table12_where_table12_col1_like_percent-n.sql
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `table11` WHERE table12.col1 LIKE '%n'': Unknown column 'table12.col1' in 'where clause' (1054)
```

Now although the following approach works technically, in reality the dumpfile has nothing inserted inside `table11` after creating it, only values are inserted inside `table12`. So the result is not what is intended -

```
mysqldump -u admin -p database1 --tables table11 --where="col1>=50"  table12 --where "col1 LIKE '%n'"> /home/payel/Documents/Unimportant/MySQLBackUp/database1_table11_where_table11_col1_greaterthanorequalto_50_table12_where_table12_col1_like_percent-n.sql
Enter password:
```

So, is there any way to achieve this or is this not possible?

If it is not possible then it has to be a drawback of MySQL demanding a feature request.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe simply `{complete command 1} && {complete command 2}`? of course for command 2 you must replace `>` with `>>`. And the password will be requested twice...

Comment: Maybe you should use into outfile rather than  mysqldump

Comment: Have you thought about using inot OUTFILe instead of mysqldump

Comment: Ok, @Akina I think this must be the best way out here

Comment: @ErgestBasha  and nbk don't know about OUTFILE syntax

Comment: @nbk don't know about OUTFILE syntax

Comment: @PayelSenapati I used like this: `select columns  from table_name  where condition  into outfile './Export.csv' fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n';`, but you can check for more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html